# Let $X = \left[ 0,1\right] \times \left[ 0,1\right] $.Determine the interior of $ A$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \left[ 0,1\right] \times \left[ 0,1\right] $, let topology be the one which is generated by next sets:
$ \langle a, b \rangle $;

$ [ \hat{a} , b \rangle $, where $ \hat{a} $ is min $ X$ if it exists ;

$ \langle a , \hat{b} ] $, where $ \hat{b} $ is max $ X$ if it exists,

considering the lexicographic order induced by standard order on$ \left[ 0, 1 \right]$. Determine the interior of 
$ A = ((\mathbb{Q} \cap \left[ 0, 1 \right] ) \times \left[ 0, 1 \rangle ) \cup (((\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} ) \cap \left[ 0, 1 \right] ) \times \langle 0, 1 \right] )$.

I think it should be Int ($A$) = $\left[ 0, 1\right] \times \langle 0 , 1 \rangle $ , but I'm not sure is it true and how to prove it.

Comment: $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are also in the interior. For the other points with second coordinate consider open intervals containing them and show these always stick out of the set.